# Duda con validación

Tags: android, android-studio

**Buenas, tengo un pequeño inconveniente a la hora de ejecutar la validación.

**Clase:**

```
public class Mensajes {
    public String text;
    public boolean usuarioAcuatl;

    public int user;

    public int getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(int user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Mensajes(String text, boolean usuarioAcuatl) {
        this.text = text;
        this.usuarioAcuatl = usuarioAcuatl;
    }

    public Mensajes(String mensaje){
        this.text = mensaje;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public Mensajes(){}
}
```

**Adaptador:**

```
public class AdaptadorMensajes extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Mensajes> mensajesList = new ArrayList<Mensajes>();
    Context context;

    public AdaptadorMensajes(Context context, ArrayList<Mensajes>arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mensajesList=arrayList;
    }

    public void add(Mensajes m) {
        this.mensajesList.add(m);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mensajesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mensajesList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        VistaDelMensaje vdm = new VistaDelMensaje();
        LayoutInflater messageInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Mensajes mensajes = mensajesList.get(i);

        if(mensajes.usuarioAcuatl) { //lado derecho
            convertView = messageInflater.inflate(R.layout.respuesta_elegida, null);
            vdm.cuerpomensaje = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.respuestaUsuario);
            convertView.setTag(vdm);
        } else { // lado izquierdo
            convertView = messageInflater.inflate(R.layout.respuesta_programada, null);
            vdm.avatar = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
            vdm.usuario = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            vdm.cuerpomensaje = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cuerpoProgramado);
            convertView.setTag(vdm);

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            String horaActual = c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            vdm.usuario.setText("Desconocido" + " - " + horaActual );
        }
        vdm.cuerpomensaje.setText(mensajes.getText());
        return convertView;
    }

    class VistaDelMensaje {
        public View avatar;
        public TextView usuario;
        public TextView cuerpomensaje;
    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```
public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        int valorGuardado= new PreferenciaIdioma(ParteUnoCapUno.this).traerIdiomaGuardado();
        eleciones = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEleccion);

        mensajesArrayList = new ArrayList<Mensajes>();
        mensajesArrayList.add(new Mensajes("Hola"));
        mensajesArrayList.add(new Mensajes("¿Cómo estas?"));

        adaptadorMensajes = new AdaptadorMensajes(this, mensajesArrayList);
        lvMensajes = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMensajes);
        lvMensajes.setAdapter(adaptadorMensajes);

        if(valorGuardado == 1){
            eleciones.setText(R.string.btneleciones);
            eleciones.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    enviarRespuesta();
                }
            });
        }else {
            eleciones.setText(R.string.btnChooses);
        }
    }

    public void enviarRespuesta(){
        int valorGuardado= new PreferenciaIdioma(ParteUnoCapUno.this).traerIdiomaGuardado();
        if(valorGuardado == 1){
            AlertDialog.Builder menu = new AlertDialog.Builder(ParteUnoCapUno.this)
                    .setTitle("¡Elige una opción!")
                    .setPositiveButton("Responder", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Mensajes mensajes = new Mensajes();
                            mensajes.usuarioAcuatl = true;
                            if(mensajes.usuarioAcuatl){
                                mensajesArrayList.add(new Mensajes("Bien, gracias, ¿Y tú?"));
                                AdaptadorMensajes adaptadorMensajes = new AdaptadorMensajes(getApplicationContext(), mensajesArrayList);
                                lvMensajes.setAdapter(adaptadorMensajes);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog listo = menu.create();
            listo.show();
        }
    }
```

Bien, la cosa es que como verán añado dos mensajes con un `Array` a través del código. Estos se añaden al lado izquiero de la pantalla, lo cual está bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, al momento de enviar una respuesta estos se tienen que visualizar en el lado derecho. Pero, no es el caso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Layout **respuesta_elegida:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingVertical="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/respuestaUsuario"
        android:background="@drawable/respuesta_usuario"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout **respuesta_programada:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingVertical="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="60dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar_desconocido"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#99000000"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nombre"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Desconocido"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cuerpoProgramado"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nombre"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nombre"
        android:background="@drawable/respuesta_programada"
        android:paddingVertical="12dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout de la `activity:`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PantallasCapituloUno.ParteUnoCapUno"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@color/negro">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearEncabezado"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="¿A dónde van las aves?"
            android:textColor="@color/negro"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearAmbos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="644dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearEncabezado"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lvMensajes"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/linearAmbos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEleccion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingHorizontal="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

¿Alguien me puede decir dónde le estoy errando? Cabe añadir que si, al adaptador le pongo `false` en la siguiente línea:

```
if(mensajes.usuarioAcuatl == false) { //lado derecho
```

Me manda todo al lado derecho:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: En el TextView "respuesta_elegida" agregas la respuesta ? si es así, podrías agregar el layout donde viene este TextView?

Comment: Listo, ya lo añadí @Elenasys

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no filtras tus mensajes. Tu mensaje tiene que ser un objeto que tenga una variable position. Entonces cuando envies respuesta pones los datos del mensaje y la posicion . Asi en tu adaptador cambias el layout por codigo la posicion del texto en base la informacion del mensaje.

Comment: Sinceramente, no entendí nada ajjaja me lo puedes mostrar? @OsAndNoTi

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo ya te respondiendo abajo es eso que tu objeto tenga una variable, q ya la tenias usuarioActual que es un booleano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que veo es que estás creando todos los mensajes usando el constructor que solo pide un String, con lo cual todos tus mensajes llevan `usuarioActual` en false.

Para arreglarlo, cuando creas la respuesta hazlo así:
`mensajesArrayList.add(new Mensajes("Bien, gracias, ¿Y tú?", true));`

ya que si no lo haces así, estarás usando el valor por defecto de `usuarioActual` que es `false`.

Aquí te dejo una tabla con los valores de las variables que no están instanciadas para que veas (sacada de la [documentación de java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)):

[image: Tabla de valores por defecto en java]

Comment: Eres un genio, muchísimas gracias era exactamente eso que dijiste.